# need to set parameter to rdlc reports dynamically in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

In `mvc4 project` we are using `.rdlc reports` `I need to show textbox to take parameter on .rdlc  reports on report name filter.`

`My problem is want to show those textboxes on report file like ssrs reports does (.rdl files)`

and I do not want to create different set of`partial views (.cshtml) files.`

any thread with example will be helpful.

> I did google but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReportViewer` control is a server-side control and require ViewState, .cshtml files doesn't work that way.

I'll try to illustrate the way i did it:

- Controllers/Report

  - ReportController

    - ActionResult Index()

      - // Display the View
    - FileResult Get (string p1, string p2 ...) // Any parameters you want.

      ```
      // Start a ReportViewer control, set the source (rdcl file), 
      // Set the parameters based on (p1, p2, etc), 
      // Use ReportViewercontrol.LocalReport.Render, specify "PDF".
      // Use the byte[] result to return a new File()
      ```
- Views/

  - Report

    - Index 
         // Place your parameters inputs. 
         // From javascript, call the ReportController/Get, render the result in a div to refresh.

Comment: I tried the same way but need to show parameter `textbox` dynamically how can I do it? I'm confused

Comment: Your text box will can be a HTML regular intput box. 

To do it "dinamically" which means going to the server and geting a new report back, you can use jQuery.ajax features. Let me find an example and update the answer.

Comment: @ashish check a sample, http://jsfiddle.net/k9jbR/. that will be your index.cshtml, you will need to set the controller right. Also, you probably need to set a particular responsetype to force to display the PDF instead of downloading it. Sorry, can't do much right now.